# SQL Sort verions numeric + string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-order-by, version

I have to sort a table by the version column which is a random string + numeric(x.xx.xx).For example my table looks like:

```
string 1.14.2
string 1.14.1
string 1.14
string 1.14.3
string 1.14.4
string 1.11
string 1.10
string 1.10.2
string 1.9
string 1.9.4
string 1.9.2
string 1.8
string 1.8.8
string 1.4.6
```

and my result has to look like:

```
string 1.14.4
string 1.14.3
string 1.14.2
string 1.14.1
string 1.11
string 1.10.2
string 1.10
string 1.9.4
string 1.9.2
string 1.9
string 1.8.8
string 1.8
string 1.4.6
```

my current sql is

````
SELECT * FROM t_plugins WHERE a_category = 'string' AND a_master_ig = 2
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(a_name), " ", -1), ".", -1)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
order by
    cast(
        substring_index(
            substring_index(a_name, ' ', -1),
            '.', 
            1
         ) 
         as unsigned
    ) desc,
    cast(
        right(
            substring_index(a_name, ' ', -1),
            length(substring_index(a_name, ' ', -1)) 
                - locate('.', substring_index(a_name, ' ', -1))
        )
        as decimal(10, 5)
    ) desc
```

The idea is to :

- separate the string from the version number
- isolate the first digit of the version number (and cast it to an integer value) and use it as the first sort criteria
- then isolate the second and third part, cast that to a decimal value, and use it as second sort criteria

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2dc81317550fc8247759b423988aaea)**:

```
| a_name        |
| :------------ |
| string 1.14.4 |
| string 1.14.3 |
| string 1.14.2 |
| string 1.14.1 |
| string 1.14   |
| string 1.11   |
| string 1.10.2 |
| string 1.10   |
| string 1.9.4  |
| string 1.9.2  |
| string 1.9    |
| string 1.8.8  |
| string 1.8    |
| string 1.4.6  |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler using implicit conversion:

```
order by substring_index(a_name, '.', 1) + 0,
         substring_index(substring_index(a.name, '.', 2), '.', -1) + 0,
         substring_index(a_name, '.', -1) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no space within your "random string", this should give you the result you expect.

```
select 
    *
from 
    your_table
order by 
    cast('/' + TRIM(SUBSTRING(your_version_col,CHARINDEX(' ', your_version_col),LEN(your_version_col)))  + '/' as hierarchyid) desc
```